# My password always rejected when try to connect Clickhouse server

Tags: clickhouse

I have an issue about Clickhouse server. I ran the server on Docker and I am trying the connect server on Java language but I have an issue. My password is always rejected but my password is correct. What can I do? Where is my mistake?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.setProperty("ssl", "false");
    prop.setProperty("sslmode", "NONE"); // NONE to trust all servers; STRICT for trusted only
    prop.setProperty("username", "default");
    prop.setProperty("password", "AufsdfFMdfsdfPffdsdBIgxasdzqqfdoıfksdfz");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ch:https://localhost:18123/", prop);

    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jdbc_test(idx Int8, str String) ENGINE = MergeTree ORDER BY idx");

    try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
            "insert into jdbc_test select col1, col2 from input('col1 Int8, col2 String')")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            ps.setInt(1, i);
            ps.setString(2, "test:" + i); // col1
            // parameters will be write into buffered stream immediately in binary format
            ps.addBatch();
        }
        // stream everything on-hand into ClickHouse
        ps.executeBatch();
    }


    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from jdbc_test");
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(String.format("idx: %s str: %s", rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2)));
    }
}
```

My error below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Code: 516. DB::Exception: default: Authentication failed: password is incorrect, or there is no user with such name.
```

Comment: You are showing us username/password and a JDBC url - but how can we verify that any of that is correct? Figure this out with the DB's admin.

Comment: I am sure, these are correct.

Comment: How do you know they are correct if you can't connect with the jdbc driver?  Can you connect to ClickHouse in your docker container with HTTP (port 8123) or clickhouse-client (port 9000)?  How did you set the password for ClickHouse in your container?

Comment: try curl `curl 'http://default:AufsdfFMdfsdfPffdsdBIgxasdzqqfdoıfksdfz@localhost:18123/?query=select+1'`

Comment: you have a character `ı` in your password. It could be an issue in JDBC/HTTP because of it. Try to use latin - ascii 128 character set.